# FreeBSD w/ two network interfaces and different domains

Tags: networking, freebsd, dns, resolv.conf

I have a FreeBSD machine with two NICs set up as follows:

- `em0 ---> IP set via DHCP (192.168.1.0/24). "home" domain`
- `em1 ---> IP set statically (10.0.0.2).  "lab" domain`

For all intents and purposes, my home domain works fine.  I can get to the internet and ping any host on the network.  Routing also works, I can ping any host from either domain from the FreeBSD machine via IP but, I can only resolve names on the home network.

I created a `/etc/resolvconf.conf` file to prepend the search domain and name server to the `resolv.conf` file as follows:

```
search_domains="lab"
name_servers="10.0.0.10"
```

I then update resolv.conf with the command:

```
$ sudo resolvconf -u
```

I can now resolve names on the `lab` network, but no longer on the `home` network.  Manually editing the resolv.conf file and reversing the order of domains and name servers results in resolving `home` but not `lab` - exactly opposite.

**How can I tell `resolv.conf` to use one DNS server for a particular domain (the statically set IP) and allow it to get the DNS info for the other IP via DHCP?**

---

Just for reference....

`/etc/rc.conf:`

```
hostname="beastie1"
ifconfig_em0="DHCP"
ifconfig_em1="inet 10.0.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0"
defaultrouter="192.168.1.1"
```

`/etc/resolv.conf`

```
# Generated by resolvconf
search lab home.
nameserver 10.0.0.10
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

The DNS "server" on the `lab` domain 10.0.0.0 is nothing more than a cheap consumer Netgear router that does provide DHCP leases.  I only have this set statically because it's a TFTP server for bootimages and I purposely set it to 10.0.0.2 for ease of use when trying to flash firmware updates on some Cisco gear.

Comment: Rather than try to straddle across two desperate DNS servers, you could try one of two alternative architectures...

A simple solution would be to use `/etc/hosts` on the FreeBSD machine to resolve *lab* addresses, leaving DNS pointing to *home* only. *This would only work for address resolution on the FreeBSD machine itself.*

Alternatively, run a DNS server on the FreeBSD machine. There are a number of ways to configure it such that unresolved domains are forwarded to the *home* DNS.

Comment: @RichardSmith I agree that in my scenario, it would simple enough to manually edit `/etc/hosts` and solve the issue, but the reason for my approach/question is more academic in nature.  I wanted to know if I was in a large network with a sizeable lab how I would accomplish this without having to modify `/etc/hosts` on every workstation in the lab.

Comment: Any workstation that can see both domains should use a DNS that can see both domains, so that unresolved requests are forwarded towards the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You are using entirely the wrong tool for the job.

This job is not done within the DNS client library.  DNS client libraries are not complex enough to make decisions about routing queries to different sets of content DNS server based upon the name being looked up.  DNS client libraries delegate the grunt work of query resolution, including this sort of stuff, to resolving proxy DNS servers.  *They* are what implement *split-horizon DNS service*, which is the mechanism that you want here.

In your case, if you are using just what comes with FreeBSD (or its derivatives such as DragonFly BSD and TrueOS) out of the box, this will be an instance of `unbound` running locally.

You do three things:

- **You run `unbound`.** Enable it to auto start with `local_unbound_enable=YES` in `/etc/rc.conf` in the usual way.
- **You configure `unbound` to perform split horizon DNS service.**  You do this with *stub zones* in `unbound.conf` for your `lab.example.com.` and your `home.example.com.` domains, denoting `10.0.0.10` and `192.168.1.1` as the content DNS servers for those domain names and everything below them.
- **You tell the DNS client library to query your server, and only your server.** You have one `nameserver` line in `/etc/resolv.conf` (from one `name_servers` key-value pair in `/etc/resolvconf.conf`) that directs your DNS client library to talk to `unbound`.

Notes:

- **You do not use `home.` and `lab.`.**  These are real top-level domain names, *that you do not own*.  `home.` is currently the subject of 10 applications at ICANN.  Use a domain name *that you own*, not ones that you do not.  Substitute that for `example.com.` in the above. **No, you do not own `local.`, `localhost.`, `dev.`, `corp.` or many others.**

  If, for example, you owned `radiantnexus.com.`, you would use `home.allan.radiantnexus.com.` and `lab.allan.radiantnexus.com.`.
- **Adjust your search domains appropriately**, if you want non-fully qualified domain names to be found in your local namespace.

  `search_domains="home.allan.radiantnexus.com lab.allan.radiantnexus.com"` to continue the aforegiven example.
- **Do not think that you can fall back to other people's resolving proxy DNS servers.**  A big mistake is to add in a resolving proxy DNS server provided by your off-the-shelf router, by your ISP, or by Google.  All of the servers that your DNS client library directly talks to *must* provide *the same view* of the DNS name space, consistent with one another.  Google Public DNS *knows nothing* about your internal namespace, for starters.  If you want a fallback DNS server, you need *another local* DNS server somewhere, configured with your *same* split-horizon setup.
- **You also need stub zones for all of the non-public IPv6 and IPv4 address-to-name lookup names.**  There are actually quite a lot of these, and the lookup traffic for them really should not be leaking out over your/your organization's borders.  And yes, they really *should* be stub zones, not local ones, if you want address-to-name lookup to work for the leases handed out by your combined DHCP/DNS server.

### Bonus content

I use djbdns (as patched by … well … me) on FreeBSD.

- The nosh toolset's configuration import subsystem sets me up with a `dnscache@127.0.0.1` service that runs a local resolving proxy DNS server, and a `tinydns@127.53.0.1` and an `axfrdns@127.53.0.1` service that runs a local root content DNS server that `dnscache@127.0.0.1` talks to.

  I enable these services with `enable` directives in `/etc/system-control/presets/20-djbwares.preset`:

  ```
  enable axfrdns@127.53.0.1
  enable cyclog@axfrdns
  enable tinydns@127.53.0.1
  enable cyclog@tinydns
  enable dnscache@127.0.0.1
  enable cyclog@dnscache
  ```
- The local root content DNS server has in its database an admixture of the public `.` data, pulled from ICANN every year or so using `axfr-get`, and data for internal names beneath domain names that I own.

  ```
  % ls -dl root/{data*,p*,root*,Makefile}
  -rw-r--r--  1 root   wheel      968 16 Sep 09:43 root/Makefile
  -rw-r--r--  1 root   wheel   571334 28 Nov 00:33 root/data
  -rw-r--r--  1 root   wheel  1088169 28 Nov 00:33 root/data.cdb
  -rw-r--r--  1 root   wheel     3243 16 Sep 09:55 root/private
  -rw-r--r--  1 root   wheel     6962 28 Nov 00:32 root/public
  -rw-r--r--  1 root   wheel   560853 11 Mar  2017 root/root
  -rw-r--r--  1 root   wheel  3668733 11 Mar  2017 root/root.zone
  %
  ```

  The `root/private` file is where I will have the private data such as:

  ```
  =machine97.jdebp.eu:192.168.100.97:::lo
  ```
- I clone the `root/servers/@` file in `dnscache@127.0.0.1` for the various split horizon prune points, so that `dnscache` knows to override any public content DNS server address information for those points that it might happen to be sent:

  ```
  % ls -dli root/servers/{@,C.E.F.ip6.arpa,machine97.jdebp.eu}
  352608 -rw-r--r--  46 root  wheel  11 23 Nov  2016 root/servers/@
  352608 -rw-r--r--  46 root  wheel  11 23 Nov  2016 root/servers/C.E.F.ip6.arpa
  352608 -rw-r--r--  46 root  wheel  11 23 Nov  2016 root/servers/machine97.jdebp.eu
  %
  ```

  (Actually, the nosh toolset sets up the private IP address ones for me, as standard.  There's a whole chapter on what gets provided and the various ways to use it, in the *nosh Guide*.)

This is a *private root* setup.  It is one of the *other* ways (there being several) of providing split-horizon DNS service with two content DNS servers.  (In the aforegiven `unbound` set up, you have a multiple content DNS server arrangement as well; your local content DNS servers being the ones on `10.0.0.10` and `192.168.1.1` on other machines on your LAN rather than a private one on `127.53.0.1` on the machine itself.)

A private root also yields me the benefit of duff DNS query traffic for nonexistent stuff, from Google Chrome's probes to stuff that is trying to reverse-map IPv6 addresses in `fec0::/12` and IPv4 addresses in `192.168.0.0/16`, not escaping to Internet at large.

You can do a private root with `unbound` too.  It is more complex than stub zones, though.  I leave that as an exercise for the reader, it being beyond the scope of this answer.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2004). *[What DNS query resolution is](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/dns-query-resolution.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2002). *[Providing "split horizon" DNS service.](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/dns-split-horizon.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2003). *[Your fallback proxy DNS servers must provide the same view of the DNS namespace as your principal one.](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/dns-client-all-proxies-must-provide-same-service.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2012). *[Use domain names that you own and don't abuse domain names that you do not own.](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/dns-use-domain-names-that-you-own.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2017). *[What DNS name qualification is](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/dns-name-qualification.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2000). *["content" and "proxy" DNS servers](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/dns-server-roles.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2004). *[Employ split horizon DNS service if you are using non-public IP address ranges.](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/dns-private-address-split-horizon.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2003). *[You've forgotten to populate your "internal" DNS database with data.](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/dns-split-horizon-common-server-names.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- Mike West (2012-02-18).  *[Chrome connects to three random domains at startup.](https://mikewest.org/2012/02/chrome-connects-to-three-random-domains-at-startup)*.  mikewest.org.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016).  "The `dnscache`, `tinydns`, and `axfrdns` services".  *[nosh Guide](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide.html)*.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). *[Daniel J. Bernstein's softwares all in one](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/djbwares/)*.  Softwares.
- "[Domain Name System](https://freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/network-dns.html)". *FreeBSD Handbook*.  FreeBSD.

Comment: That's a lot to digest.  I did want to clarify that the `home` and `lab` domains are private and I wasn't (in the least) expecting public DNS servers to handle those name resolutions.  I should have added that my main firewall is a pfsense router with DNS enabled and the "cheap" Netgear is a DD-WRT upgrade with DNSmasq running to serve as a DNS server for the lab.