# DNS: Domain-dependant resolution possible?

Tags: dns, resolv.conf

Is it possible to configure a domain-depentant nameserver for address-resolution (e.g. resolv.conf)?

e.g.

```
nameserver 1.2.3.4 for any domain abc.com
nameserver 4.3.2.1 for any domain cba.com
nameserver 1.4.2.3 for anything else
```

I am using a modern Debian.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can’t do this with only `resolv.conf`, but with an intermediary DNS forwarding daemon such as [Dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) (packaged in Debian as `dnsmasq` and related packages).

With Dnsmasq, you’d configure Dnsmasq itself with the list of servers:

```
server=/abc.com/1.2.3.4
server=/cba.com/4.3.2.1
server=1.4.2.3
```

and tell it not to look at `resolv.conf`:

```
no-resolv
```

Then you’d change your `resolv.conf` so it points to the Dnsmasq daemon, by removing all the `nameserver` entries therein. You’d also need to ensure that any DHCP setup doesn’t overwrite `resolv.conf`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  It's been possible for a quarter of a century.  What you are looking for is *split horizon DNS service*, and it is not done by fiddling with `/etc/resolv.conf`.  That configuration file dictates stuff to the DNS client library that is (usually) built into the C library that applications programs link to.  That library is *simple* and does not do complex decisions like working out where to send different queries to based upon their question sections.

It's done by fiddling with the (machine-local or site-local) *resolving proxy DNS server* that the DNS client libraries are configured to talk to.  In concrete terms: The `/etc/resolv.conf` settings point applications to a resolving DNS proxy server listening on (say) a socket bound to the IPv4 address 127.0.0.1, and *that* server is configured, in ways that are specific to the server software, to enact query resolution in the appropriate way. *That proxy DNS server*, or even the content DNS server(s) *that it in its turn talks to*, is where all of the split-horizon mechanism resides.

- In ISC's BIND, this is done with *conditional forwarding* or with *stub zones*.
- In Daniel J. Bernstein's dnscache this is done with `servers/domain` files.
- In dnsmasq, this is done in yet another way.  As too systemd-resolved.  And so forth.

So install one of these server softwares (Debian even having some of them pre-packaged) on your Debian machine, configure the DNS client libraries to use it, and configure it to do split-horizon DNS.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2002). *[Providing "split horizon" DNS service.](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/dns-split-horizon.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/413646/5132